# Download a generated file and redirect in Django

Tags: django

I have a form with which users submit data to my application, and the response to submitting the form is a download with data depending on what they submitted. Since the submission affects the data in the database I want to redirect from this page to prevent the submission accidentally being made twice.

The only solution I've come across is to save the file on the server and redirect to a page which causes the file to download. However I don't really want to be keeping these files or having to manage them on the server.

Is there a way to download the file and then cause the page to redirect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider also the case when the user's internet connection happens to break during the download. Should the user have a possibility to request the same download again in this case? Then you need to store either the generated file or all data needed to regenerate it anyway.

Comment: OK I'll accept this as a good enough reason not to do it. Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

presumably there are two parts to your code, one adding their data to your db, and a second generating their download. could you just do the first part on form submit, and then redirect them (perhaps including some get parameters) to a second page which reads the db and generates their download?

Comment: not all of the information to be included in the download is saved to the database, and it is not necessarily obvious which data has just been added, and hence should go in the download